# convert APNs auth key to use with PyJWT

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications, pyjwt

**Context**

I am using `pyjwt` to generate a jwt to send push notifications from a python backend to APNs (Apple Push Notification service). My backend is running on a standard GAE (Google App Engine) instance, so I must use the legacy packages `pycrypto` and `ecdsa` instead of `cryptography` within `pyjwt` ([docs](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)).

**Problem**

My `auth_key.p8` (which I downloaded from Apple Developer) is formatted `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`, but the `ecdsa` package expects it to be formatted `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----`. Hence I get the following traceback:

```
  File "app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 65, in encode
    json_payload, key, algorithm, headers, json_encoder
  File "app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 113, in encode
    key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)
  File "app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/contrib/algorithms/py_ecdsa.py", line 44, in prepare_key
    key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_pem(key)
  File "app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ecdsa/keys.py", line 189, in from_pem
    privkey_pem = string[string.index(b("-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----")):]
ValueError: subsection not found
```

It seems that my `auth_key` is in a format that `ecdsa` does not accept, but I don't know what to do to fix this. Am I supposed to convert this `auth_key` into a different format?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: looking back through my code, looks like I gave up and decided to use Firebase instead. They offer a python sdk, and handle the connection to APNS themselves. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by having a newline at the end of the key. After removing the newline the error went away.